# Authlogic Facebook Connect and cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cucumber, authlogic

I added the [authlogic_facebook_connect](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect) plugin to my project and I'm now having problem running my cucumber test because of a NoMethodError.

```
undefined method `set_facebook_session' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

In authlogic_facebook_connect/Session.rb the method "authenticating_with_facebook_connect?" is called as some sort of callback and the controller is defined but is missing the 'set_facebook_session' method.

```
  def authenticating_with_facebook_connect?
    controller.set_facebook_session
    attempted_record.nil? && errors.empty? && controller.facebook_session
  end
```

I don't understand why the cucumber test is not loading the controller with this method.
I also test the app in development and cucumber environments and everything works perfect.

Here is the full cucumber output.

```
Feature: Authentication
  In order to keep security a user should only be able to edit their own profile

  Background:                                # features/authorization.feature:4
    Given a valid user record for joe_runner # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:4
      undefined method `set_facebook_session' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:63:in `send'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:63:in `method_missing'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic_facebook_connect/lib/authlogic_facebook_connect/session.rb:132:in `authenticating_with_facebook_connect?'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:83:in `validate'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/session/validation.rb:64:in `valid?'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/session/existence.rb:65:in `save'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/session/existence.rb:30:in `create'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:113:in `create_session'
      ./vendor/plugins/authlogic/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:103:in `maintain_sessions'
      ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:5:in `/^a valid user record for ([\w]*)$/'
      features/authorization.feature:5:in `Given a valid user record for joe_runner'

  Scenario: Jonathan can edit his profile but not other users profiles # features/authorization.feature:7
    Given jonathan is logged in as an user                             # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:13
    When I go to my user edit page                                     # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:18
    And I press "Update"                                               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:22
    Then I should see "Account updated!"                               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:142
    When I go to joe_runner's user edit page                           # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:18
    Then I should see "You do not allowed to access to view that page" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:142

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/authentication.feature:9 # Scenario: Signup
cucumber features/authorization.feature:7 # Scenario: Jonathan can edit his profile but not other users profiles

2 scenarios (2 failed)
15 steps (2 failed, 13 skipped)
0m0.173s
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:995:in `sh'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `sh'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `sh'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1029:in `ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:68:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:138:in `define_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
activespoon:base_project jspooner$
```

There are a couple of blogs that give examples on how to test facebook apps with cucumber but they didn't help because my error comes before these.
http://opensoul.org/2009/3/6/testing-facebook-with-cucumber
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/03/testing-facebook/

Comment: You can also see get the source code on github
http://github.com/jspooner/authlogic_cucumber_rspec_example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with my test suite after installing authlogic_facebook_connect.
I applied the following patch to the plugin and it solved the problem:

http://gist.github.com/221893